# Why when i am searching for something else is deleting the previous contents

Tags: javascript, api

Why when you are searching for something else is deleting the previous contents ?For example first you search for egg and show the contents but then when you search for beef the program deletes the egg and shows only beef.Code :

```
const searchBtn = document.getElementById('search-btn');
const mealList = document.getElementById('meal');
const mealDetailsContent = document.querySelector('.meal-details-content');
const recipeCloseBtn = document.getElementById('recipe-close-btn');

// event listeners
searchBtn.addEventListener('click', getMealList);
mealList.addEventListener('click', getMealRecipe);
recipeCloseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    mealDetailsContent.parentElement.classList.remove('showRecipe');
});


// get meal list that matches with the ingredients
function getMealList(){
    let searchInputTxt = document.getElementById('search-input').value.trim();
    fetch(`https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=${searchInputTxt}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        let html = "";
        if(data.meals){
            data.meals.forEach(meal => {
                html += `
                    <div class = "meal-item" data-id = "${meal.idMeal}">
                        <div class = "meal-img">
                            <img src = "${meal.strMealThumb}" alt = "food">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "meal-name">
                            <h3>${meal.strMeal}</h3>
                            <a href = "#" class = "recipe-btn">Get Recipe</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                `;
            });
            mealList.classList.remove('notFound');
        } else{
            html = "Sorry, we didn't find any meal!";
            mealList.classList.add('notFound');
        }

        mealList.innerHTML = html;
    });
}
```

Comment: `innerHTML = html` _replaces_ the existing HTML of the element. It doesn't _add_ to it. Use `innerHTML += html` or look at [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) as an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are replacing the contents in the mealList element every time.

A simple workaround would be to retrieve the the innerHTML values before you update it.

Something like

```
let html = mealList.innerHTML;
```

rather than starting off empty every time you call the function should do the trick.